# Feeding inlet power into a generator transfer switch

Tags: wiring, generator, transfer-switch

I'm installing a manual transfer switch for a generator in my basement. The transfer switch box requires that the inlet connect come from the bottom of the box. However, I will be running the wiring for the inlet box along the basement rafters.

What is the best way for me to make a 180 degree turn from the ceiling into the bottom of the transfer switch box? I'm using 10/3 romex for the interior wiring.

This is the transfer switch I am using: https://www.connecticut-electric.com/10-circuit-transfer-switch-kit-egs107501g2kit

Comment: Please post the model number of the transfer switch. Maybe the thing can be turned over?

Comment: What kind of cable and/or conduit?  It's normal to bend them around corners, as I'm sure you know, so a little more detail on why it's a problem would help.

Comment: It might be appropriate to drill a new knock-out in the top or side of the box for easier wire routing. Model number or a photo of it will help us assess.

Comment: I've edited the post to include a link to the transfer switch

Comment: Chinetticut Electric is not quality stuff, it's cheaply made trash.  I would consider a sliding plate generator interlock instead if you can find one to fit your panel. It will require far less wiring, cleaner install, works properly with MWBC, GFCI and AFCI, and lets you switch any load. It wires into the existing panel (no new box) and best of all it's 1/5 the price.

Comment: @harper-reinstate-monica I would need to completely rewire my existing panel to do this. The necessary location for the interlock breaker is full and I would need to move every circuit in the panel due to the wire lengths.

Comment: You definitely can't turn that unit upside down!  The door will fall on the floor, the meters and labeling will be upside down.  What problem exactly are you trying to solve?  Is it physical protection of the cable as it runs down and into the bottom of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A J bend in the protective conduit sleeve you'll require (when you leave the ceiling) if this is exposed wiring, or the same thing in the concealed wall space (or a protected by plywood space you build out from the wall just for this purpose) with the cable. Make large radius turns, they are easier to pull wire or cable through and don't damage the cable if you don't need conduit due to being in-wall. That may mean offsetting the switch from the cable location so you have room for a nice big J along the wall surface, rather than trying to make a quick-turn in a few inches.

Comment: Do you think this could be done with flexible conduit? I don't have a bender.

Comment: Perhaps FMC (flex metal, not liquidtight) - my experience is that liquidtight (either flavor - metallic or non-metallic) is a horribly sticky pull. You could also buy a pre-bent sweep, or you could run to a box suitable to the scale of your cable and make the turn in the box. I'd probably just frame up a wiring chase from wood and plywood, in your shoes.